# Get a Map<String, List<Pojo>> from List<Pojo> in Java 8

Tags: java, list, dictionary, collections, java-8

I have a `Student` class. The structure of the class is:

```
class Student {
    
    String name;
    int age;
    String grade;
    
    //Getters and Setters

}
```

I have a `List` of such `Student`s:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
//Populate the list with some instances of Student.
```

Now, for a particular business requirement, I need to get a `Map<String, List<Student>>` from the `students` `List`.

The "key" of the `Map` should be a value of the `grade` property of the `Student` class.

The "value" of the `Map` should be the `List` of all such `Student`s having that `grade`.

For example,

If my `students` `List` is like this:

```
[{"Student1", 10, "A1"}, {"Student2", 12, "A2"}, {"Student3", 10, "A1"}, {"Student4", 11, "A1"}, {"Student5", 10, "A2"}, {"Student6", 10, "A1"}, {"Student7", 11, "B1"}]
```

I should get a `Map` like this:

```
{
    "A1" : [{"Student1", 10, "A1"}, {"Student3", 10, "A1"}, {"Student4", 11, "A1"}, {"Student6", 10, "A1"}],
    "A2" : [{"Student2", 12, "A2"}, {"Student5", 10, "A2"}],
    "B1" : [{"Student7", 11, "B1"}]
}
```

Please note that primarily I am looking for a solution using Java 8, while the older ways are also most welcome.

Comment: the [documentation of `Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) has an example

Comment: All right, I got a simple solution. Thanks.

```Map<String,List<Student>> groupedMap =
students.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGrade));```